# What to call someone who laughs off an offense you've taken?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

For example, someone strongly offended you and you let them know, maybe hoping for an apology, acknowledgement or just a change in his attitude. Instead he laughs it off, ignores your concern by saying "haha, so what have you been up to/how are you?"

What would you call a person like this?

Comment: I'd say you can call him anything you want. If he gets offended, just laugh it off.

Comment: Is it something like an explanation of how magnets work, or gravity that has offended you? The answer to your question is highly dependent on what the supposedly offensive words or deeds were.

Comment: FWIW, you seem to ask **only** questions about what to call someone whom you don't appreciate or who does something you don't appreciate (8 for 8, so far). Why not loosen up a bit? There's more to the English language & its usage than name calling. Just a friendly suggestion - hope you don't feel offended by it. And I don't mean that there is anything wrong with asking such questions. But maybe you have some other questions also?

Answer (score 4):

***[Unapologetic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unapologetic)*** might fit.

> not feeling or showing regret or shame : not apologetic

*impenitent* is a synonym also.

Answer (score 1):

*Insensitive* is the word I would use.

Answer (score 0):

Insensitive; rude; thoughtless; non-caring; banal

Answer (score 0):

Consider [**unconcerned**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unconcerned).

> *unconcerned*: lacking in interest or care or feeling

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps *callous* or *oblivious to the feelings of others.*

Answer (score 0):

I would call them [ruthless](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ruthless), [incompassionate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/incompassionate),  or *cold-hearted*.

> having or showing no pity