# Adjective for someone that tries to gloss over past insults?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

This person would say things that wound you and then after an hour she comes to you all smiley and tries to make up for the things she said. Not in a serious manner but really lightheartedly, saying things like

> 'You know I didn't mean it :D'
>
> 'Hey are you mad? XD'

I don't know. It's not mushy - mushy is different.

Comment: I don't know either. Fickle? Mercurial? Those aren't quite right.

Comment: Did she really mean it when she said the hurtful things? Or does she just have no filter?

Comment: Dear Abby, ,,,..

Comment: An ex-friend is what I'd call her... or "not worth my time".

Comment: @Jim asks relevant questions about your friend's intent. Were the hurtful utterances malicious or merely insensitive? Answering those questions would clarify your request.

Comment: **thoughtless** comes to mind. If she had thought for a moment before saying the hurtful thing, she would not have said it (since she seems to regret it immediately).  On the other hand, if she really isn't sorry,  she is _teasing_ you_ and/or _toying with your emotions_ (in cruder terms, she is _jacking you around_.)

Comment: Unsure if this question is a duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172369/what-to-call-someone-who-laughs-off-an-offense-youve-taken , as additional answers are given this time round.?

Comment: a soft synonym of "insensitive" or "oblivious (of others' feelings)" would work... perhaps `air-headed` (a colloquial term)?

Comment: Have we got the answer you want yet @Pansy?

Answer (score 1):

*Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) lists the possibly relevant term **soft-soaper** under its main entry for *soft-soap*:

> **soft-soap** *vt* (1634) **:** to soothe or persuade with flattery or blarney ***syn*** see CAJOLE — **soft-soaper** *n*

The dictionary's head-to-head comparison of the terms *cajole*, *coax*, *soft-soap*, *blandish*, and *wheedle* has this to say about *soft-soap*:

> SOFT-SOAP refers to using smooth and somewhat insincere talk usu. for personal gain {politicians *soft-soaping* eligible voters}

So if the person's attempts to persuade you to "get over it" are successful, she's a skilled soft-soaper; and if they aren't, she's an ineffectual soft-soaper.

Answer (score 0):

**emollient**

From http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/emollient:

> Attempting to avoid confrontation or anger; calming or conciliatory.
>
> "At the local carabinieri station, an officer was more emollient: ‘By the end of the month everything should be resolved."

Answer (score 0):

If you think something might be socio-emotionally amiss with this person, it can be fun to flip through the *Diagnostic and Statistical Manual of Mental Disorders* and just slap a diagnosis on them like **Borderline Personality Disorder**. Some adjectives related to common BPD behavior include:

- Manipulative
- Unstable
- Defensive
- Passive Aggressive

You might also describe this person as being **in denial**. Someone who is in denial of responsibility will often resort to minimizing or blaming  their behavior.

- "Minimizing" is an attempt to make their actions appear to have been
  harmless. They are minimizing their behavior when, after doing
  something awful, they say, "It was no big deal."
- "Blaming" is a statement that shifts culpability of a consequence. A
  person could be said to be blaming you if, after doing something
  inappropriate, they say, "What are you so mad about? You must have
  gotten up on the wrong side of the bed this morning! Don't take
  everything so seriously!"

It's also possible that you are dealing with a **narcissist**, either in the pathological schizotypal sense, or just the 'typical American teenager' sense.

Colloquial, non-psychodiagnostic terms that could apply here include **saccharine, fake, conniving, disingenuous, nonchalant, unphased, glib** and **shallow**.

Right off the top, however, the first adjective that sprang to mind for me, was **bitchy**.

Answer (score -1):

Flippant or crass.
"marked by disrespectful levity or casualness" Urban Dictionary

Manic. Maniacal. Manipulative. Sociopathic. Bipolar.

Comment: I take it the down vote is because I used Urban Dictionary as a reference.

Comment: I'd have voted someone up, but I just lack the reputation due to this down vote.